# How do I abort Windows signoff (while signing off)

Tags: windows-server-2016, user, sign-out

During a maintenance task on our Windows 2016 server, something triggered the user from being signed off.
The problem is that this user is running business critical software (as user).

This software is unfortunately very clunky, and requires a backup to be made before shutting it down. So naturally, I would like to make the backup first before killing it.

Fortunately, this software is also blocking Windows from actually signing off.
So the server is now on the "Signing off" screen for a while, in some kind of limbo.

So my question here is:

- Can I abort the signout procedure?
- Or can I somehow get back into the user session, and back in to the windows explorer? (I can sign in as another user)?

Comment: From another user console, I tried running 'shutdown /a' from a command prompt, but it said that no shutdown procedure was running, which is correct, it's only signing off, not shutting down.

Comment: There's no way to abort the sign off, but given the sign off is waiting for something, if you can kill the tasks from another user, it may allow the sign off to continue. If not, then you will need to reboot the server.